# Tool to capture every event details from other applications

Tags: events, user-interface, automation, screen-readers

Is it possible to create a Windows application to capture all event details (control type,event type,window etc) triggered from different types of applications (winform, wpf, silverlight, etc)

I tried the "record" tool in "white framework".

http://white.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Recorder&referringTitle=Home
But this tool is not detecting every events in my application.Iam looking for developing similar kind of application.

If it is possible please give some guidance.I need this for automating the testing of some applications. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the application you want to automate. If it's Win32, WinForms or WPF you might look at [Windows UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx).

Also it depends on what kind of events your are talking about. Which event is missing from the White recording tool?

**Update:**  The best Tool to see/discover the kind of UI Automation events you can record from a third party application is [Inspect.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (formerly called UISpy.exe).

In there you can record actions/events and browse through the element tree with all available properties. My experience is: if you can't see it there, you can't automate it with UI Automation.

Comment: I tried the "white recording" tool with WPF applications, but its not detecting events like tab control click events, custom control click events etc. I want to create a tool to detect each and every events from all controls, is it possible with Windows UI Automation?

Comment: @user960881 UI Automation needs to be implemented by the application you try to automate. This could be the case because the application is build ontop of a library such as .net or Win32 which support UI Automation or because the manufacture implemented UI Automation. see my updated answer.